# Changing Firefox Developer Tools

Tags: firefox-developer-tools

I am trying to make some changes to the Firefox Dev Tools. I am starting by adding console.log statements. Where should the output show up? What are the alternatives? How should I (attempt) to debug the Firefox Dev Tools? I have already successfully expanded omni.ja and rebuilt omni.ja from the expanded JavaScript. When I add (deliberately) bad code to the expanded JavaScript, the Firefox Dev Tools fail (which makes sense). However, when I add console.log statements, I can't find the output. Note that I am using (trying to use) remote debugging. However, I am not sure that is the correct approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The errors are logged to the [Browser Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console), which can be opened by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>. The same messages can also be seen when opening the Console panel within the [Browser Toolbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Toolbox), which can be opened via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> once it is enabled.

Having said that, the proper way to make changes to the Firefox DevTools is to set up a development environment for Firefox as described at https://docs.firefox-dev.tools/getting-started/.

Comment: I understand that this may be bad SO form... But Thank you.

Comment: So, did my answer actually help you?

Comment: SZ, Yes it did.

Comment: Glad to hear that!