# How Do I Change/Enhance/Modify The Firefox Developer Tools

Tags: firefox-developer-tools

I am trying to make some changes to the Firefox Dev Tools. I am starting by adding console.log statements. Where should the output show up? What are the alternatives? How should I (attempt) to debug the Firefox Dev Tools? Note that I have already expanded omni.ja and rebuilt omni.ja as need be.

Comment: This question is actually a duplicate of 61267253 and should be closed / deleted

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing Firefox Developer Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61267253/changing-firefox-developer-tools)

Comment: SZ, Yes it does. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is actually a duplicate of 61267253 and should be closed / deleted

Comment: Sebastian Zartner answered this question. Thank you.